# Get Max memory used by a windows process

Tags: c#, process

We use the .NEW ProcessStartInfo class in C# to launch windows processes, and then look at the exit codes and log files once each process is completed.

I would like to know the maximum memory used by each process.  I can get this while the process is running, but really only want to know once the process has exited.  All of the properties involving memory seem to only be available while the process is running.  Is there any way to get data about a process once it has exited?

Comment: Process does not exist after it has exited. So its memory size = 0

Comment: But there was a Max memory being tracked during its lifetime.  It seems this should be available.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a Thread to monitoring the process constantly and write the log to know the last memory number.

For what i know you don´t have a exited event to know the last memory of the process.

Comment: There is an Exited event that we hook into.  It contains the process, but at that point we only have access to the exit code.